# Rails - Query One Model from within a Different Model with a has_many & belongs_to relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm not entirely clear on how to query a models data from within a different model in Rails. The models have a has_many & belongs_to relationship. The 2 models are "Gear" and "line_item". **Gear** has_many line_items and **LineItem** belongs_to Gear.

What I'm trying to do is query all the line_items in the database that belong to a Gear object that have a NULL or Blank cart_id (this is one of the fields) and then calculate it's availability. Since in this case the Gear is rented out at certain dates and times that are stored in a line_item (start_date, end_date, start_hour, end_hour) ..Having not done a lot of advanced quering in Ruby I Googled around and now I'm not sure if how I should use

*Enumerable in the Gear Model with something like this:*

```
line_items.inject(0) {|line_item| line_item.where('line_items.cart_id' => NULL }
```

*Or if I could use a scope in the Gear Model like this:*

```
scope :availablegear, lambda { includes(:line_items).where('line_items.cart_id' => nil) }
```

I know the syntax on both is probably not correct so I could use some direction on what to use and how to use it.

Thanks.

MY Project is using Rails 3.2.0, Ruby 1.9.4 & MySQL

EDIT with Suggested Answer

```
class Gear < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :title, :size, :price, :sub_category_id, :user_id, :image, :image_a, :image_b, :image_c, :image_d, :image_e, :image_f, :image_g, :image_h, :image_i, :remote_image_url, :color, :year, :latefee, :cancellation, :minrental, :policy, :about, :address, :city, :state, :zip, :country, :latitude, :longitude, :gmaps
  ...some code omitted for brevity
  has_many :line_items
  scope :availablegear, joins(:line_items).where(:line_items => {:cart_id => nil})
  ...some code omitted for brevity

end
```

Now when I boot up Rails console and I do a g = Gear.find(4) and then do g.availablegear I get the following error: **NoMethodError: undefined method `availablegear' for #**

Comment: what do you want to get back as a result? gears or line items?

Comment: I'm trying to get line items back

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're trying to get line items back:

```
class Gear < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :line_items
end

class LineItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :gear

  scope :available, where(:cart_id => nil)
end
```

Then if you have a gear, you can call

```
gear.line_items.available
```

which will return line items that belong to `gear` and have no `cart_id`.

Answer (score 4):

I think the query you're looking for is

```
Gear.joins(:line_items).where(:line_items => {:cart_id => nil})
```

You can put it in a scope in the `Gear` class:

```
class Gear< ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :available, joins(:line_items).where(:line_items => {:cart_id => nil})
end
```

You can find some more help in the [Rails Query Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html) (see 11.3 for joining with conditions).

Comment: When I'm calling the scope don't I just do something like Gear.find(4).available? ....Right now I'm getting an Undefined Method Error in the Rails Console. I'm updating my code above

Comment: @DaveG You suse it like this `Gear.available` and you get a Relation for all the gears containing at least one line_items without cart_id.